# How can attributes be hidden under specific requirements?

Tags: angular-material

I have this element defined in template:

```
<mat-accordion class="" [multi]="true" hideToggle>
</mat-accordion>
```

I need to disable hideToggle attribute in the element above when the page is displayed on the device.

How can attributes be hidden under specific requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an attribute - it's an input value of the component. Meaning you can assign this value from your variable, same as you did with your `multi` input, e.g.

```
<mat-accordion class="" [multi]="isMulti" [hideToggle]="isToggleHidden">*
```

Of course you need to have those defined in your .ts file and have some logic that would change those value.

Here's an [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsdhbj).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as input directive.

Create a variable inside component.ts file to indicate whether it should be enabled or disabled.

```
public hideToggle: boolean = true;
```

Then in html use it like below:

```
<mat-accordion [hideToggle]="hideToggle">
```

[Example in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgv6xc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Under a specific requirment:

```js
Element.removeAttribute("hideToggle");
```

And add it back when required:

```js
Element.setAttribute("hideToggle");
```